# select all records holding some condition in has_many association - Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

I have a `model profile.rb` with following association

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_one :profile
end

class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :skills
    belongs_to :user
end
```

I have a `model skills.rb` with following association

```
class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :profile
end
```

I have following entries in skills table

```
id:         name:           profile_id:
====================================================
1           accounting          1
2           martial arts        2
3           law                 1
4           accounting          2
5           journalist          3
6           administration      1
```

and so on , how can i query all the profiles with ,lets say, "accounting" & "administration" skills which will be profile with id 1 considering the above recode. so far i have tried following

```
Profile.includes(:skills).where(skills: {name: ["accounting" , "administration"]} )
```

but instead of finding profile with `id 1` - It gets me `[ 1, 2 ]` because profile with id 2 holds `"accounting" skills` and it's performing an `"IN" operation` in database

Note: I'm using `postgresql` and  question is not only about a specific id of profile as described (which i used only as an example)  - The original question is to get all the profiles which contain these two mentioned skills.

My activerecord join fires the following query in postgres

```
SELECT FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE "skills"."name" IN ('Accounting', 'Administration')
```

In below [Vijay Agrawal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45384100/3728916)'s answer is something which i already have in my application and both, his and mine, query use `IN` wildcard which result in profile ids which contain either of skills while my question is to get profile ids which contain both the skills. I'm sure that there must be a way to fix this thing in the same query way which is listed in original question and i'm curious to learn that way . I hope that i'll get some more help with you guys - thanks

**For clarity, I want to query all the profiles with multiple skills in a model with has_many relationship with profile model - using the `Profile` as primary table not the `skills`**

**Reason for using Profile as primary table** is that in pagination i don't want to get all skills from related table ,say 20_000 or more rows and then filter according to `profile.state` column . instead anyone would like to select only `5 records` which meet the `profile.state , profile.user.is_active and other columns condition` and match the skills without retrieving thousands of irrelevant records and then filter them again.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Please rephrase your question. It does not make sense to "find all profiles with accounting skills with profile id 1" because that can only be a single profile. If that's what you meant, then you go through the association: `profile = Profile.find(1); profile.skills.where(name: %w(accounting administration))`

Comment: @anothermh it's totally clear. i'm not finding skills of profile(1) - while i'm want to get all the profiles which contain these two mentioned skills - however i update my question with the same comment too for other members

Comment: I think you'll have to provide more details on the pagination issue you're seeing. Both answers seem reasonable without that information.

Comment: @Max that's not important . that's why i mentioned the real question in the end - you can ignore pagination issue

Comment: Nor sure which part you mean by the "real question." Do you mean "I want to query all the profiles with multiple skills in a model with has_many relationship with profile model - using the Profile as primary table not the skills"? I think Vijay gave you that in his update. The updated answer from anothermh is good too, but doesn't meet your criteria of using a "has_many" relationship. Though I agree with him that has_and_belongs_to_many looks like a better choice here.

Comment: @max both of those answers result in a query which use "IN" wildcard and select either of skills but i want a profile which has both the skills

Comment: @Max you can check the sql results they mentioned in their answer

Comment: Right, the SQL results have `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses that make them select just the ones with both skills.

Comment: There must be something else going on with your app if that isn't working. The answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/19464293/7151673 uses similar syntax, though it's mostly as SQL instead of in "Rails" form.

Comment: @Max no man, there is difference - that guy gets the features and use group clause and finds one theme in result . which is not my question.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should do this to get all `profile_id`s which have both accounting and administration skills :

```
Skill.where(name: ["accounting", "administration"]).group(:profile_id).having("count('id') = 2").pluck(:profile_id)
```

If you need profiles details, you can put this query in where clause of `Profile` for `id`.

Note the number `2` in query, it is length of your array used in where clause. In this case `["accounting", "administration"].length`

UPDATE::

Based on updated question description, instead of `pluck` you can use `select` and add subquery to make sure it happens in one query.

```
Profile.where(id: Skill.where(name: ["accounting", "administration"]).group(:profile_id).having("count('id') = 2").select(:profile_id))
```

More over you have control over sorting, pagination and additional where clause. Don't see any concerns over there which are mentioned in question edit.

UPDATE 2::

Another way to get intersect of profiles with both the skills (likely to be less efficient than above solution):

```
profiles = Profile

["accounting", "administration"].each do |name|
  profiles = profiles.where(id: Skill.where(name: name).select(:profile_id))
end
```

Comment: Good answer, but isn't the ActiveRecord method `group` and not `group_by`?

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.

Comment: @ImranNaqvi Like I mentioned once you get profile_id, you can query `Profile`

Comment: @imrannaqvi Doing that in one query means just using output of above query in where clause of `Profile`. Like this:
`Profile(id: Skill.where(name: ["accounting", "administration"]).group(:profile_id).having("count('id') = 2").select(:profile_id))`

Comment: @imrannaqvi This is just giving you profile_id, so not sure what pagination problem you mentioned about. Skill.where(name: ["accounting", "administration"]).group(:profile_id).having("count('id') = 2").pluck(:profile_id)

Comment: @VijayAgrawal this is result of you query `SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" IN (SELECT "skills"."profile_id" FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."name" IN ('Accounting', 'Administration') GROUP BY "skills"."profile_id" HAVING count('id') = 2)`

Comment: you can see it is making the "IN" wildcard use. which will get the profiles id containing either of the skills . while my query is to get profile id which have both skills

Comment: Unless you are implying there is **exactly** one profile which is supposed to have 2 skills, `IN` is perfectly fine.

Comment: Also I do understand your rationale behind downvoting this answer, the answer is a very serious attempt to solve **your** problem and in no ways undermines the discussion in this post

Comment: @ImranNaqvi Have you tried it? I don't have it set up to test, but it looks like it should work fine. The `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` change what the query selects.

Comment: Going through your reply, looks like you are making assumption you don't understand. All I can say is just try the solution it if you don't understand what `IN` means. `IN` doesn't work the way you are describing in your comment.

Comment: @VijayAgrawal i do understand what `IN` means and you need to put `Profile.where(` instead of just `Profile` in your query otherwise it won't even work

Comment: That's a typo. `Profile.where` is correct syntax. But that will also have `IN`.

Comment: yes - and still gets the profiles which contain only one of the skills instead of both

Comment: Can you  double check you `skills` table and make sure there are profiles in output which have just one skill. Can you post your table (all skills for that profile) for one such profile

Comment: The only reason I can think it's possible is if you have duplicates in your `skills`. Meaning same `profile_id`, same skill `name` but different `id`. Is duplicate a correct state of table considering your business logic?

Comment: Fixed typo with missing `where` keyword

Comment: Try this for you skills table having duplicates: `Profile.where(id: Skill.where(name: ["accounting", "administration"]).group(:profile_id).having("count('distinct name') = 2").select(:profile_id))`

Comment: this should be a correct way to do that `Profile.where(id: Skill.where(name: ["accounting", "administration"]).group(:profile_id).having("count('id') = 2").select(:profile_id))`

Comment: @ImranNaqvi Did you find a solution?

Comment: @VijayAgrawal no

Comment: @ImranNaqvi @VijayAgrawal 's updated answer works, this expression `Profile.where(id: Skill.where(name: ["accounting", "administration"]).group(:profile_id).having("count('id') = 2").select(:profile_id))` produces this query `SELECT  "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."id" IN (SELECT "skills"."profile_id" FROM "skills" WHERE "skills"."name" IN ('accounting', 'administration') GROUP BY "skills"."profile_id" HAVING (count('id') = 2))`

Answer (score 4):

```
Profile.includes(:skills).where("skills.name" => %w(accounting administration))
```

For more information, read about [finding through ActiveRecord associations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594533/activerecord-find-through-association?rq=1).

**Update**

If this is not working for you then you likely do not have your database and models properly configured, because in a brand new Rails app this works as expected.

```
class CreateProfiles < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :profiles do |t|
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateSkills < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :skills do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.integer :profile_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :profile
end

Profile.create
Profile.create
Skill.create(name: 'foo', profile_id: 1)
Skill.create(name: 'bar', profile_id: 1)
Skill.create(name: 'baz', profile_id: 2)

Profile.includes(:skills).where("skills.name" => %w(foo))
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "profiles"."id" FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE "skills"."name" = 'foo' LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "skills"."id" AS t1_r0, "skills"."name" AS t1_r1, "skills"."profile_id" AS t1_r2, "skills"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "skills"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE "skills"."name" = 'foo' AND "profiles"."id" = 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-28 21:52:56", updated_at: "2017-07-28 21:52:56">]>

Profile.includes(:skills).where("skills.name" => %w(bar))
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "profiles"."id" FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE "skills"."name" = 'bar' LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "skills"."id" AS t1_r0, "skills"."name" AS t1_r1, "skills"."profile_id" AS t1_r2, "skills"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "skills"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE "skills"."name" = 'bar' AND "profiles"."id" = 1
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-28 21:52:56", updated_at: "2017-07-28 21:52:56">]>

Profile.includes(:skills).where("skills.name" => %w(baz))
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "profiles"."id" FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE "skills"."name" = 'baz' LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  SQL (0.1ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "skills"."id" AS t1_r0, "skills"."name" AS t1_r1, "skills"."profile_id" AS t1_r2, "skills"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "skills"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" WHERE "skills"."name" = 'baz' AND "profiles"."id" = 2
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 2, created_at: "2017-07-28 21:53:34", updated_at: "2017-07-28 21:53:34">]>
```

**Update 2**

Downvoting an answer because you changed your question later is poor form.

You should change your model relationships from `has_many` and `belongs_to` to [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_and_belongs_to_many). This will allow you to stop recording a new skill every time; if someone adds the skill `administration` and then later on someone else adds that skill, you don't have to create a new skill. You just re-use the existing skill and associate it with multiple profiles:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :skills
end

class Skill < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles
end
```

Add a join table with a unique index (so each profile can have each skill once and only once):

```
class Join < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :profiles_skills, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :profile, index: true
      t.belongs_to :skill, index: true
      t.index ["profile_id", "skill_id"], name: "index_profiles_skills_on_profile_id_skill_id", unique: true, using: :btree
    end
  end
end
```

Create your models:

```
Profile.create
Profile.create
Skill.create(name: 'foo')
Skill.create(name: 'bar')
Skill.create(name: 'baz')
Profile.first.skills << Skill.first
Profile.first.skills << Skill.second
Profile.second.skills << Skill.second
Profile.second.skills << Skill.third
```

And then run your query to return just the first profile:

```
skills = %w(foo bar).uniq
Profile.includes(:skills).where('skills.name' => skills).group(:id).having("count(skills.id) >= #{skills.size}")
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "profiles"."id" FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_skills" ON "profiles_skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."id" = "profiles_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "skills"."name" IN ('foo', 'bar') GROUP BY "profiles"."id" HAVING (count(skills.id) = 2) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "skills"."id" AS t1_r0, "skills"."name" AS t1_r1, "skills"."profile_id" AS t1_r2, "skills"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "skills"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_skills" ON "profiles_skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."id" = "profiles_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "skills"."name" IN ('foo', 'bar') AND "profiles"."id" = 1 GROUP BY "profiles"."id" HAVING (count(skills.id) = 2)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-28 21:52:56", updated_at: "2017-07-28 21:52:56">]>
```

Confirm with additional testing:

Should return both profiles:

```
skills = %w(bar).uniq
Profile.includes(:skills).where('skills.name' => skills).group(:id).having("count(skills.id) >= #{skills.size}")
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "profiles"."id" FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_skills" ON "profiles_skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."id" = "profiles_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "skills"."name" = 'bar' GROUP BY "profiles"."id" HAVING (count(skills.id) >= 1) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "skills"."id" AS t1_r0, "skills"."name" AS t1_r1, "skills"."profile_id" AS t1_r2, "skills"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "skills"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_skills" ON "profiles_skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."id" = "profiles_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "skills"."name" = 'bar' AND "profiles"."id" IN (1, 2) GROUP BY "profiles"."id" HAVING (count(skills.id) >= 1)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 1, created_at: "2017-07-28 21:52:56", updated_at: "2017-07-28 21:52:56">, #<Profile id: 2, created_at: "2017-07-28 21:53:34", updated_at: "2017-07-28 21:53:34">]>
```

Should return just the second profile:

```
skills = %w(bar baz).uniq
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "profiles"."id" FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_skills" ON "profiles_skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."id" = "profiles_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "skills"."name" IN ('bar', 'baz') GROUP BY "profiles"."id" HAVING (count(skills.id) >= 2) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  SELECT "profiles"."id" AS t0_r0, "profiles"."created_at" AS t0_r1, "profiles"."updated_at" AS t0_r2, "skills"."id" AS t1_r0, "skills"."name" AS t1_r1, "skills"."profile_id" AS t1_r2, "skills"."created_at" AS t1_r3, "skills"."updated_at" AS t1_r4 FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_skills" ON "profiles_skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."id" = "profiles_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "skills"."name" IN ('bar', 'baz') AND "profiles"."id" = 2 GROUP BY "profiles"."id" HAVING (count(skills.id) >= 2)
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Profile id: 2, created_at: "2017-07-28 21:53:34", updated_at: "2017-07-28 21:53:34">]>
```

Should return no profiles:

```
skills = %w(foo baz).uniq
Profile.includes(:skills).where('skills.name' => skills).group(:id).having("count(skills.id) >= #{skills.size}")
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT  DISTINCT "profiles"."id" FROM "profiles" LEFT OUTER JOIN "profiles_skills" ON "profiles_skills"."profile_id" = "profiles"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "skills" ON "skills"."id" = "profiles_skills"."skill_id" WHERE "skills"."name" IN ('foo', 'baz') GROUP BY "profiles"."id" HAVING (count(skills.id) >= 2) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

Comment: it's the same query except for you used it in other way - but produces the same result as mine - i'm putting query result in question if it could make it more better

Comment: you are checking it for one skill at a time .... it works but for more than 2 skills search - it fails

Comment: I think the question is looking for all the profiles that have both the accounting and administration skills, not all the ones that have either.

Answer (score 2):

`PostgreSQL` dependent solution:

```
where_clause = <<~SQL
  ARRAY(
    SELECT name FROM skills WHERE profile_id = profiles.id
  ) @> ARRAY[?]
SQL
Profile.where(where_clause, %w[skill1 skill2])
```

It works, but it makes sense to change DB structure for speed-up. There are two options:

- `has_and_belongs_to_many` way adds consistency (`skills` tables turns into the dictionary) and ability to use indexes
- `skills` as `array`|`jsonb` column of `profile` - adds fast search by index without sub-selects or joins.

Comment: I am interested in your answer.
Would you like to add exact sample for above question?
clarify `where_clause`.

Comment: @LucasH. What is unclear? Type `Profile.where(where_clause, %w[skill1 skill2]).to_sql` to get SQL query. Read `PostgreSQL` doc about `ARRAY`s and `@>` operator.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `EXISTS` with a [correlated sub-query](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery), like this:

```
required_skills = %w{accounting administration}
q = Profile.where("1=1")
required_skills.each do |sk|
  q = q.where(<<-EOQ, sk)
    EXISTS (SELECT 1
            FROM   skills s
            WHERE  s.profile_id = profiles.id
            AND    s.name = ?)
  EOQ
end
```

There are some other ideas at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42455920/ruby-on-rails-has-many-through-find-multiple-conditions/42561314#42561314) but I think in your case multiple `EXISTS` clauses is the simplest and most likely fastest.

(By the way in Rails 4+ you can start with `Profile.all` instead of `Profile.where("1=1")`, because `all` returns a `Relation`, but in the old days it used to return an array.)

Comment: It would do one "pass" of skills table for every `required_skills`. Might be slower than the group/having solution already posted. On side not, you don't need to do either `.all` or `.where....` just `q = Profile` should work

Comment: `q = q.where(<<-EOQ, sk)` what's this meaning?

Comment: @LucasH. the `EOQ` is a [heredoc](https://infinum.co/the-capsized-eight/multiline-strings-ruby-2-3-0-the-squiggly-heredoc), inherited from the shell and Perl. It double-quotes everything down to the matching token (here `EOQ`). So I'm saying `q.where("EXISTS (. . . s.name = ?)", sk)`.

Answer (score -1):

The problem with the following query

`Profile.includes(:skills).where(skills: { name: ["accounting" , "administration"] } )` is that it create a query with `IN` operator like `IN ('Accounting', 'Administration')`

Now as per the SQA standard, it will match all the records which matches any value and not all the values from the array.

Here is a simplest solution

```
skills = ["accounting" , "administration"]

Profile.includes(:skills).where(skills: { name: skills }).group(:profile_id).having("count(*) = #{skills.length}")
```

P.S. This assumes you will have at least one skill. Adjust `having` condition as per your usecase

Comment: `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::GroupingError:` no matter what group by id i  change